# Computing the Euler characteristic of a variety via cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

By Grothendieck's vanishing theorem, every variety $ X $ over a field $ k $ has a finite cohomology sequence; i.e. we have an exact sequence

$$ 0 \to H^0(X, \mathcal{O}) \to \cdots \to H^r(X,\mathcal{O}) \to 0 \to 0 \to \cdots $$

where each cohomology group $ H^i $ is a module over $ k $. Set $ h^i = \dim H^i(X, \mathcal{O}) $ for each $ i $.

Now by rank-nullity, the alternating sum $ h^0 - h^1 + \cdots \pm h^r $ is just $ 0 $.

But this final alternating sum is just the Euler characteristic of $ X $ - which is obviously not zero for every variety.

We are having some trouble finding the mistake (which is probably really obvious) - any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think there is such an exact sequence? (There's not!)

Comment: Yes thanks for your comment - this is exactly the problem... obviously not enough coffee was drunk today...

Comment: @Geometrystudent72 also keep in mind that the holomorphic Euler characteristic (the alternating sum of $h^i(X,\mathcal O_X)$) is NOT the same invariant as the topological Euler characteristic, which is what I would typically think when I hear the phrase "Euler characteristic of a variety" (at least when $k=\mathbb C$).

Comment: @TabesBridges I think in algebro geometric context this should always be clear from context. Certainly for someone starting algebraic geometry over a general field they will encounter the 'coherent euler characteristic' much sooner than the encounter the 'etale euler characterstic' or whatever. Since they didn't specify $k$, I think then it is fairly clear.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Maybe? I came to AG via Riemann surfaces, so $\chi_{top}$ (computed using singular cohomology or whatever, NOT etale cohomology!) was certainly familiar to me as a part of the story before I knew anything about sheaf cohomology. I also spent at least a little bit of time (stupidly) wondering if $\chi_{top}$ and $\chi$ of a vector bundle were in any way related (then I remembered that vector bundles deformation retract onto their base space).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the mistake turned out to be really obvious...

We thought that there was a long exact sequence like the one in the question that we could obtain from the cohomology groups, but this was a mistake (obviously there is a complex involved, namely the one induced from an injective resolution $ 0 \to \mathcal{O} \to \mathcal{O}^0 \to \mathcal{O}^1 \to \cdots $, i.e. $ 0 \to \Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}^0) \to \Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}^1) \to \cdots $, and our mistake was thinking that this set up a natural exact sequence of the quotients $ H^i $, which it does not).